# How to have script detect if terminal emulator is running in a desktop session or not?

Tags: scripts, desktop-environments, virtual-console

I have scripts I run that write out a text file, then open it in an editor.  If I open a terminal emulator window in my desktop session and run the script, I'd like the editor to be a graphical one such as `gedit`. But, if I'm logged in through ConnectBot on my phone or similar (no desktop session), I'd like the editor to be `nano`.

Currently I have to maintain 2 different scripts, identical except for the last step (or let the graphical one run, error off, then manually open the file in `nano`).  Having two mostly identical scripts is inefficient from a maintenance standpoint.

Can a script detect which of these situations I'm in, and open the correct editor?

(I have found ways for a script to detect whether it's running in a terminal emulator window or by being double-clicked, but not yet found a way to detect if the window is running in a desktop...I don't think I know the correct terminology to google for)

Comment: If your script is for use by other people you should use the program specified by `$EDITOR` by default instead of `nano`, and fallback on `nano` if it is not set.

Comment: Thanks, great advice, and it's great to hear what is good practice.  Just me though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `$DISPLAY` as trigger within a `if` condition. Usually when this variable has a value you are able to run graphical applications.

Here is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) example:

```bsh
if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]]
then
    nano
else
    gedit
fi
```

The operator `-z` will return true when the envvar `$DISPLAY` is empty and your script will run `nano`, in all other cases it will run `gedit`.

---

According to the this comment of [@vurp0](https://askubuntu.com/users/259797/vurp0):

> On most modern Wayland desktops (like the default desktop in Fedora
>   and Ubuntu), `$DISPLAY` is still set due to backwards compatibility
>   (through XWayland), but for a more robust script it would be good to
>   test for both `$DISPLAY` and `$WAYLAND_DISPLAY` to be sure.

I would suggest to modify the test expression in the following way:

```bsh
[[ -z ${DISPLAY}${WAYLAND_DISPLAY} ]]
```

Thus, the values of the two variables will be concatenated into a common string, which will be processed by the operator `-z`.

---

References:

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: 7.   Tests](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tests.html)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: 7.1. Test Constructs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: 7.3. Other Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: Or for explicit logic: `[[ -z ${DISPLAY} && -z ${WAYLAND_DISPLAY} ]]`

Answer (score 7):

Typically virtual terminals use [`/dev/pts` pseudo-terminals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93640/85039). So, based on the output of `tty` command, we can build a simple `case` statement to handle opening particular editor:

```
case "$(tty)" in ; "/dev/pts"*) nano ;; "/dev/tty"*) gedit ;; ;esac
```

Or formatted more nicely:

```
case "$(tty)" in
    "/dev/pts"*) gedit ;; 
    "/dev/tty"*) nano ;;
    *) echo "Not suitable tty" > /dev/stderr ;;
esac
```

Compared to using environment variables, this is slightly more reliable and considering it uses `case` statement with `tty` command slightly more portable. What probably would be best is to combine both, with extra testing, such as `"/dev/tty"*) [ -n "$DISPLAY" ] && gedit ;;`

Comment: Isn't this the wrong way around? On my Ctrl+Alt+F1 console, `tty` gives `/dev/tty1`, whereas `gnome-terminal` (first tab) gives `/dev/pts/0`.

Comment: @PaddyLandau Yes, `gedit` should be in `/dev/pts*` case. I switched them around while error testing in tty and ended up copying it here without switching back. Thanks, edited already.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've been using:

```bash
# $TERM variable may be missing when called via desktop shortcut
CurrentTERM=$(env | grep TERM)
if [[ $CurrentTERM == "" ]] ; then
    notify-send --urgency=critical "$0 cannot be run from GUI without TERM environment variable."
    exit 1
fi
```

The reason for this code was this question: [Desktop shortcut to Bash script crashes and burns](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019464/desktop-shortcut-to-bash-script-crashes-and-burns)

You can modify it to look like this:

```bash
# $TERM variable may be missing when called via desktop shortcut
CurrentTERM=$(env | grep TERM)
if [[ $CurrentTERM == "" ]] ; then
    nano ...
else
    gedit ...
fi
```